# HT16K33 Datasheet Query

Tags: led-driver

I'm an enthusiastic amateur when it comes to electrical engineering, and have been looking at using the HT16K33 matrix driver. What confuses me is on page 6 of the [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ht16K33v110.pdf) where it references I<sub>OH1</sub> the row source current and provides two typical values, one for V<sub>OH</sub>=V<sub>DD</sub>-2V and one for V<sub>OH</sub>=V<sub>DD</sub>-3V. Does anyone have any pointers on how to interpret those two different values? Do they relate to the forward voltage of the LED somehow?

I'm just keen not to blow up the first LEDs I connect to this IC. Thanks.

Comment: you forgot to edit after pasting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

What the data sheet tells me is that if you try to take typically 30 mA from the pin, the row voltage output will be Vdd - 3 volts. So if Vdd is 5 volts, you will typically see an output voltage of 2 volts.

If your LED has a volt drop of nominally 2 volts, it will be fed approximately 30 mA. If your LED has a volt drop of 3 volts then it will only take typically 25 mA.

But you also have to take into account what the column volt drop might be - it could be as high as 0.3 volts if dumping 200 mA but, with a proper multiplexing system it is likely to be just a few tens of millivolts. However, this didn't become absolutely clear in the few minutes I was reading it.

Comment: Thanks I think that just about makes sense, constant current drivers are weird.